# When running "make" on Mocha.js tests, on mounted drive, get Permission Denied error 127

Tags: linux, node.js, makefile, mocha.js

I have a node.js app located in an ntfs mounted drive in linux (Ubuntu).  The makefile contents look like:

```
test:
    @./node_modules/.bin/mocha -u tdd
```

When running "make test" on this, I get the error:

```
make: execvp: ./node_modules/.bin/mocha: Permission denied
make: *** [test] Error 127
```

This even happens when running "sudo make test"

When listing the permissions of that directory, there is execute permissions on that file:

```
ls -l node_modules/.bin/
total 3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 208 2012-05-01 14:15 express
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 191 2012-05-01 14:15 express.cmd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 200 2012-05-01 14:15 mocha
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 202 2012-05-01 14:15 _mocha
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 185 2012-05-01 14:15 _mocha.cmd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 183 2012-05-01 14:15 mocha.cmd
```

Copying this directory to a location outside of the mounted drive, and running "sudo make test" there succeeds.

It is mounted via /etc/fstab as the line:

```
/dev/disk/by-label/Files    /media/d    ntfs-3g defaults,user,local=en_US.utf8 0 0
```

How can I get this to work within the ntfs mounted drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The volume is mounted `noexec`. Remount it `exec` instead.

Comment: I added how it's currently mounted to the question.  How would I modify that to mount it as exec?

Comment: Stick `exec` somewhere after `user`.